# How would I display vBulletin threads

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am wondering how I'd display threads on my website from my forums. For instance, inside a div on my website, I'd want to display "the latest 5 threads" or whatever. My forum is on a separate website, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post any code you've tried or an explanation of what you've already done to implement on your site.

Comment: I haven't attempted anything. I'm just asking for where I can start. How would I go about doing this. What to look into, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "external data provider" ("yourforum.com/external.php").

See [this](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/options_group_externaldata) and [that](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/vboptions_group_external) links for documentation and configuration.

For instance, you can get a single forum activity with : (for forum id 17)

```
external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=17
```

Then you need to parse the RSS feed to print it properly into you web site.